# Regex for matching successive strings

Tags: regex

What kind of regex should I use if I wanted to match a group of characters but only match if two groups are the same?

For example, the following should match

`Hello John, Goodbye John.
Hello Amy, Goodbye Amy.`

But these should not match

`Hello John, Goodbye Amy.
Hello Amy, Goodbye John.`

Comment: Is it only for the above line you want to match or will you have a string varying in the number of words in it?

Comment: Is your criteria that the name should be the same in a row? Is there a specific set of predicates (Hello/Goodbye) or do you want to check after any punctuation? Is it part of a large block of text or a series of sentences? You need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your regex engine, you can use backreferences in the regex to refer (and match) previously matched items:

```
Hello (\w+), Goodbye \1.
```

This produces a match only if the text after "Goodbye" exactly matches the first match (i.e. the word after "Hello").

Example usage (in Python):

```
>>> re.findall(r'Hello (\w+), Goodbye \1.', 'Hello John, Goodbye John. Hello Amy, Goodbye Amy. ')
['John', 'Amy']
>>> re.findall(r'Hello (\w+), Goodbye \1.', 'Hello John, Goodbye Amy. Hello Amy, Goodbye John. ')
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using backreferences is an easy way to tackle this problem. These are references to previously parenthesized elements in the expression.

For example, the below will only match if the backreference matches "John":

/Hello (John), Goodbye ($1)/

The $1 will ensure the second element matches the first.

More applicable to your problem, the below will allow any word characters (names):

/hello (\w+), goodbye ($1)/gi

Cheers,
G

Comment: As far as I know, that will simply try to match `$` (end of line/string) and `1`, I don't know any regex flavor that does back-referencing like that. It works when replacing, but not during the match. Also, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think it's Perl. `perl -e 'print "Hello John, Goodbye John" =~ /Hello (John), Goodbye ($1)/'`

Comment: @nneonneo - I don't know much perl, but: **1.** http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html has no mention of it. **2.** It looks like `$1` tries to insert the value of the current `$1` into the pattern, much like `$varname`. It should be nothing (empty) when you create the regex, so it is the same as `/hello (\w+), goodbye ()/`. Quick test: http://ideone.com/nOp2B , Here's another fun one, where we capture `$1`: http://ideone.com/YPOH2

Comment: You're right. I made a hasty assumption. So, then, the question remains: does that work in any language?